# i can't access the function of master page in content page in vb.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

i make info() function in master page and i want to access this function in content page.but i can't access info() function in content page.in the code new_user and register_user are labels.
master page function is:

```
Public Sub info(ByVal a As Integer)
    If a = 1 Then
        new_user.Visible = False
        register_user.Visible = True
    Else
        new_user.Visible = True
        register_user.Visible = False
    End If
End Sub
```

it is not accessible in contentpage

Comment: From your content page try something like `Dim masterPage As MasterPageClass = CType(Page.Master, MasterPageClass)` and then `masterPage.info`

Comment: yes..it woring good thank you